# Keep column of table fixed size

Tags: css, sass

I am currently building a site and a section of a page has a table within the middle column of an outer 3 column table. I am trying to get that inner table (or the middle column of the bigger table) to not change size when the window is being resized.

Currently when the window is resized, the 2 outside columns of the big table all shrink together which shrinks the middle column and thus my table inside of that column. I would like the resizing to only take away from the outer columns of the big table and not resize the middle column. I hope this made some sense. #tableception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use CSS and place a fixed width on the center table that you  have within your main table. I'll assume your center table has the id "centertable":

```
<style type='text/css'>
#centertable {
  width: 200px;
}
</style>

<table id="centertable">
....
</table>
```

This fixes the width to 200px. You could use the CSS min-width property to set a minimum width (which allows the table to shrink only to a certain size), and/or the max-width property to set a maximum width as well.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer seems to be to just set a specific width for the column you don't want to change (in your case the middle one if I understand correctly). However, it would be very helpful if you also posted some code or even a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

**To select the middle column you can use:**

```
table tr td+td {
   width: 200px; //Your preferred width
}

//OR
table tr td:nth-child(odd) {
   width: 200px; //Your preferred width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a fixed width in the first column cell (probably a `<th>`). Example:

```
th.middle-column {
    with: 300px;
}
```